# debugging signals in a django application on a production server

Tags: django, debugging

In settings.py I have setup a way to log my messages like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    filename = 'log/sdout.log',
    filemode = 'a'
)
```

However sometimes django fails silently. Like in the case of signals. My problem is that at my work pc everything works great. At my production server something is wrong. I know the place of the exception. I just can't see why it fails.

So I placed something like this:

```
logging.debug('before error') #this is printed out
try:
    end_date = start_date.date() + relativedelta(months = +month_diff)
    next_billing_date = start_date.date() + datetime.timedelta(7)
except :
    import sys, traceback
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)

logging.debug('after error') #I never get to that part.
```

EDIT: The above snippet lies in my `models.py` called when I receive a POST from paypal

After failure I try to look into my apache error logs and my logging file but see no errors, whatsoever.

How can I see what is wrong with this code?

Comment: How are you calling the code? wsgi?

Comment: this code snippet is placed in my models.py. It is called when the paypal POSTs for my notify_url. (if that answers your question)

Comment: How did you wire it up with your web server? mod_wsgi, mod_python, etc?

Comment: Maybe you could try and install [django-sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry). It'll also report server errors that typically aren't as visible (such as code executed upon a POST callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first recommended sentry - if you can't install it due to system restrictions - it is now available as a hosted service at [getsentry.com](https://www.getsentry.com/welcome/) and like most such services, there is a free tier.

However, the issue could be that WSGI by default blocks writing to `stdout`, as detailed [in the documentation wiki](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Writing_To_Standard_Output) under application issues.

There are few workarounds posted at that page, but the one I would start with is to add the following to your WSGI configuration:

`WSGIRestrictStdout Off`

See if that helps with error logging.